# Parameters that can be tracked using Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am not sure this question is valid on this platform or not but asking here.
We have an android application and we want to integrate our app with Google Analytics so that we can track its usage. But we are not sure yet that for the android app, which parameters can be tracked using Google Analytics.

We need parameters like number of app crashes, app version, number of app restarted, and many more like that. It would be very helpful if I get the list of all those parameters we can track using Google Analytics. If some configuration is required in app's code, we can do that.

Comment: You can do that - check these links https://www.google.dk/analytics/mobile/  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

Comment: Dimenson and metrics reference is here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=app